# Play framework, best way to search for data, finder vs lists

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, performance

I recently started to use play framework and i have a basic question.
I have this 2 models:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

...
private int age;
@ManyToOne
private Project project;
...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Project extends Model {

...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
private List<User> members = new ArrayList<User>();
...
}
```

Now, for one Project p, I want to find all the users with 20 years old.
What is the best way to do it?

Should I create a function in project model to search the list

```
public List<User> getUsers(int age){
    List<User> temp = new ArrayList<User>();
    for(User u : members)
        if(u.getAge() == age)
            temp.add(u);

    return temp;
}
```

or should I use a finder

```
 List<User> temp = User.find.where.eq("age", 20).eq("project", p).findList();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many code efficiency question : It depends of your use case.

In one hand, if you load (from the database) a project and display all its members after doing something with specific members (here users with age = 20), to search into a the list already loaded is more efficient.

To search in a list means that all the data in the list will be loaded (if this list is lazy loaded).

In the other hand, if you only doing something with specific users and nothing with other members, only loading the specific members from the database is quickier.

Using a finder let the database limit the data to load in the application (again if the list is lazy loaded), but will reload again the specific members if the list is already eagerly loaded.

Mostly, ORM will lazy load one to many relations. And if you don't need other members for this request you should use the finder method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just one more question,
if I load a project to use another information like name etc,
the members list won't be loaded until I call it, or as soon as I load the project (Project p = ...) all information will be loaded?

Comment: As I wrote, ORM will lazy load one to many relations (but you can configure to eagerly fetch it). Until you call project.members, they won't be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a list, that means you have to load all users from the database into your application.  If you don't have many users in the database (eg, less than 100), then maybe that's not a problem.  If you have millions of users in the database, your application will fall over, as the database tries to send MB or GB of data to it with all the users.

If you use a finder, that results in a SQL call on the database that just gets the results you want.  Furthermore, if you create an index on the project and the age field, then the database can very efficiently do the search, it doesn't have to loop through each user, it can just go to the index and get the results in a single step.

Also, if the number of users at that age is very large, you may want to do paging.  Using a finder, you can get the database to do the paging, so you only get the current page, instead of having to load all the results into your application and then exclude the pages you aren't interested in.

In general, you should always put the load of finding data on the database, so you should always use a finder.